# JAXB- Not able to bind this xsd to java objects

Tags: java, xsd, xml-parsing, jaxb

I am using HyperJAXB sample code of purchase order from http://confluence.highsource.org/display/HJ3/Purchase+Order+Tutorial This example works fine for me. I Am able to create java objects from XSD and persist it into DB. Now I am trying with my XML and XSD.
I am not able to bind following xsd using JAXB. I am using eclipse built in tool as well as HyperJAXB, but both failed to parse my XSD.
I have generated this xsd from xml using online tool:  http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html

There are multiple problems:

1. xml:lang=" en-us - gives an eror for this and  even if we remove this, there is problem in binding.
2. [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project hyperjaxb3-ejb-template-basic-maven: Comp
   ilation failure: Compilation failure:
   [ERROR] E:\App\SampleCode\hyperjaxb3-ejb-template-basic-0.5.6-maven-src\hyperjaxb3-ejb-template-basic-0.5.6\target\generated-sources\xjc\generated\CXML.java:[599,7] error
   : duplicate class: generated.CXML
   [ERROR] E:\App\SampleCode\hyperjaxb3-ejb-template-basic-0.5.6-maven-src\hyperjaxb3-ejb-template-basic-0.5.6\src\test\java\generated\ObjectFactory.java:[32,7] error: dupli
   cate class: generated.ObjectFactory

It generates only two classes, not rest of classes

1. generated\CXML.java
2. generated\ObjectFactory.java

Can someone help me making this XSD to bind successfully and generate java objects out of it.

XSD:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xs:element name="cXML">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="Header">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="From">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="Credential">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element type="xs:string" name="Identity"/>
</xs:sequence>
<xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="domain"/>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="To">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="Credential">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element type="xs:string" name="Identity"/>
</xs:sequence>
<xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="domain"/>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Sender">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="Credential">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element type="xs:string" name="Identity"/>
</xs:sequence>
<xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="domain"/>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Request">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="OrderRequest">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="OrderRequestHeader">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
<xs:element name="ID">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:simpleContent>
<xs:extension base="xs:short">
<xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="domain"/>
</xs:extension>
</xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Total">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="Money">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:simpleContent>
<xs:extension base="xs:float">
<xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="currency"/>
</xs:extension>
</xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Shipping">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="Money">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:simpleContent>
<xs:extension base="xs:float">
<xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="currency"/>
</xs:extension>
</xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Description">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:simpleContent>
<xs:extension base="xs:string">
<xs:attribute ref="xml:lang"/>
</xs:extension>
</xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Tax">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="Money">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:simpleContent>
<xs:extension base="xs:float">
<xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="currency"/>
</xs:extension>
</xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Extrinsic">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:simpleContent>
<xs:extension base="xs:string">
<xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name"/>
</xs:extension>
</xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="BillTo">
<xs:complexType mixed="true">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="Address" minOccurs="0">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element type="xs:string" name="CompanyName"/>
<xs:element name="ContactId">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:simpleContent>
<xs:extension base="xs:int">
<xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="domain"/>
</xs:extension>
</xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element type="xs:string" name="PaymentType"/>
<xs:element name="PostalAddress">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element type="xs:string" name="FirstName"/>
<xs:element type="xs:string" name="LastName"/>
<xs:element type="xs:string" name="Street"/>
<xs:element type="xs:string" name="City"/>
<xs:element type="xs:string" name="State"/>
<xs:element name="Country">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:simpleContent>
<xs:extension base="xs:string">
<xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="isoCountryCode"/>
</xs:extension>
</xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element type="xs:int" name="PostalCode"/>
<xs:element type="xs:string" name="Email"/>
<xs:element type="xs:long" name="WorkPhone"/>
</xs:sequence>
<xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name"/>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
<xs:attribute type="xs:int" name="contactId"/>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
<xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name" use="optional"/>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Contact">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="ID">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:simpleContent>
<xs:extension base="xs:string">
<xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="domain"/>
</xs:extension>
</xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element type="xs:string" name="Name"/>
<xs:element type="xs:string" name="Email"/>
<xs:element type="xs:string" name="Company"/>
<xs:element type="xs:string" name="Department"/>
</xs:sequence>
<xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="Role"/>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:choice>
<xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="orderDate"/>
<xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="type"/>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="ItemOut">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element type="xs:string" name="Type"/>
<xs:element name="ItemId">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:simpleContent>
<xs:extension base="xs:int">
<xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="domain"/>
</xs:extension>
</xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element type="xs:string" name="StatusType"/>
<xs:element name="PostageAmount">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:simpleContent>
<xs:extension base="xs:float">
<xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="currency"/>
</xs:extension>
</xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Discount">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:simpleContent>
<xs:extension base="xs:float">
<xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="currency"/>
</xs:extension>
</xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element type="xs:string" name="orderItemName"/>
<xs:element type="xs:string" name="orderItemDescription"/>
<xs:element type="xs:float" name="Price"/>
<xs:element name="ItemID">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element type="xs:string" name="SupplierPartID"/>
<xs:element type="xs:string" name="SupplierPartAuxiliaryID"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="ItemDetail">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element type="xs:string" name="URL"/>
<xs:element name="Description">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:simpleContent>
<xs:extension base="xs:string">
<xs:attribute ref="xml:lang"/>
</xs:extension>
</xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="UnitPrice">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="Money">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:simpleContent>
<xs:extension base="xs:float">
<xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="currency"/>
</xs:extension>
</xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element type="xs:string" name="UnitOfMeasure"/>
<xs:element name="Extrinsic">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="ul">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="li" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
<xs:complexType mixed="true">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element type="xs:float" name="span"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
<xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name"/>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Classification">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:simpleContent>
<xs:extension base="xs:string">
<xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="domain"/>
</xs:extension>
</xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element type="xs:string" name="ManufacturerPartID"/>
<xs:element name="ManufacturerName">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:simpleContent>
<xs:extension base="xs:string">
<xs:attribute ref="xml:lang"/>
</xs:extension>
</xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="ShipTo">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="Address">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="ContactId">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:simpleContent>
<xs:extension base="xs:int">
<xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="domain"/>
</xs:extension>
</xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element type="xs:string" name="CompanyName"/>
<xs:element name="PostalAddress">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element type="xs:string" name="FirstName"/>
<xs:element type="xs:string" name="LastName"/>
<xs:element type="xs:string" name="Street"/>
<xs:element type="xs:string" name="City"/>
<xs:element type="xs:string" name="State"/>
<xs:element name="Country">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:simpleContent>
<xs:extension base="xs:string">
<xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="isoCountryCode"/>
</xs:extension>
</xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element type="xs:int" name="PostalCode"/>
<xs:element type="xs:string" name="Email"/>
<xs:element type="xs:long" name="WorkPhone"/>
</xs:sequence>
<xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name"/>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
<xs:attribute type="xs:int" name="contactId"/>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Shipping">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="Money">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:simpleContent>
<xs:extension base="xs:float">
<xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="currency"/>
</xs:extension>
</xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Description">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:simpleContent>
<xs:extension base="xs:string">
<xs:attribute ref="xml:lang"/>
</xs:extension>
</xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Distribution" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="Accounting">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="AccountingSegment" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="Name">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:simpleContent>
<xs:extension base="xs:string">
<xs:attribute ref="xml:lang"/>
</xs:extension>
</xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Description">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:simpleContent>
<xs:extension base="xs:string">
<xs:attribute ref="xml:lang"/>
</xs:extension>
</xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
<xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="id" use="optional"/>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
<xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name" use="optional"/>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Charge">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="Money">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:simpleContent>
<xs:extension base="xs:string">
<xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="currency" use="optional"/>
</xs:extension>
</xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Comments">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:simpleContent>
<xs:extension base="xs:string">
<xs:attribute ref="xml:lang"/>
</xs:extension>
</xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
<xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="quantity"/>
<xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="lineNumber"/>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
<xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="payloadID"/>
<xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="timestamp"/>
<xs:attribute ref="xml:lang"/>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>

 XML:
<cXML payloadID="7ece55bf-8af9-42c4-9f5b-613ac5e00819" timestamp="12/4/2014 4:51:22 PM" xml:lang=" en-us ">
<Header>
<From>
<Credential domain="web">
<Identity>UAT Master</Identity>
</Credential>
</From>
<To>
<Credential domain="web">
<Identity>notused</Identity>
</Credential>
</To>
<Sender>
<Credential domain="web">
<Identity>notused</Identity>
</Credential>
</Sender>
</Header>
<Request>
<OrderRequest>
<OrderRequestHeader orderDate="12/4/2014 4:51:22 PM" type="new">
<ID domain="Web">645</ID>
<Total>
<Money currency="USD">129.48</Money>
</Total>
<Shipping>
<Money currency="USD">12.57</Money>
<Description xml:lang="en-US"/>
</Shipping>
<Tax>
<Money currency="USD">8.91</Money>
</Tax>
<Extrinsic name="Additional Comments or Instructions:"/>
<BillTo>
<Address contactId="210306">
<CompanyName>UAT Master</CompanyName>
<ContactId domain="Web">210306</ContactId>
<PaymentType>CREDITCARD</PaymentType>
<PostalAddress name="default">
<FirstName>test</FirstName>
<LastName>test</LastName>
<Street>Hills Road</Street>
<City>NYC</City>
<State>NY</State>
<Country isoCountryCode="USA">USA</Country>
<PostalCode>78759</PostalCode>
<Email>test@test.com</Email>
<WorkPhone>2342423434</WorkPhone>
</PostalAddress>
</Address>
</BillTo>
<Extrinsic name="Purchase Order Number:"/>
<Contact Role="buyer">
<ID domain="Web">John</ID>
<Name>John M</Name>
<Email>test@test.com</Email>
<Company>UAT Master</Company>
<Department/>
</Contact>
</OrderRequestHeader>
<ItemOut quantity="120" lineNumber="1">
<Type>PRINT</Type>
<ItemId domain="Web">210300</ItemId>
<StatusType>APPROVED</StatusType>
<PostageAmount currency="USD">0.00</PostageAmount>
<Discount currency="USD">0.00</Discount>
<orderItemName>cxml test for cc payment</orderItemName>
<orderItemDescription>test cxml only with cc payment</orderItemDescription>
<Price>108.00</Price>
<ItemID>
<SupplierPartID>BUSCRD001</SupplierPartID>
<SupplierPartAuxiliaryID/>
</ItemID>
<ItemDetail>
<URL>
http://47.59.13.45/ACV3UATRepo/NgA=/MQAzADUAOAAwAA==/2012/3/28/someImage==.jpg
</URL>
<Description xml:lang="en-US">Business Card</Description>
<UnitPrice>
<Money currency="USD">0.90</Money>
</UnitPrice>
<UnitOfMeasure>PER_PIECE</UnitOfMeasure>
<Extrinsic name="options">
<ul>
<li>
Envelope Color/Yellow=
<span>0.00</span>
</li>
<li>
Paper Type/Gloss=
<span>0.00</span>
</li>
</ul>
</Extrinsic>
<Classification domain=""/>
<ManufacturerPartID/>
<ManufacturerName xml:lang="en-US"/>
</ItemDetail>
<ShipTo>
<Address contactId="210301">
<ContactId domain="Web">210301</ContactId>
<CompanyName>UAT Master</CompanyName>
<PostalAddress name="default">
<FirstName>test</FirstName>
<LastName>test</LastName>
<Street>Hills Road</Street>
<City>NYC</City>
<State>NY</State>
<Country isoCountryCode="USA">USA</Country>
<PostalCode>78759</PostalCode>
<Email>test@test.com</Email>
<WorkPhone>2342423434</WorkPhone>
</PostalAddress>
</Address>
</ShipTo>
<Shipping>
<Money currency="USD">12.57</Money>
<Description xml:lang="en-US">Fedex Ground</Description>
</Shipping>
<Distribution>
<Accounting name="DistributionCharge">
<AccountingSegment id="">
<Name xml:lang="en-US"/>
<Description xml:lang="en-US"/>
</AccountingSegment>
<AccountingSegment id="">
<Name xml:lang="en-US"/>
<Description xml:lang="en-US"/>
</AccountingSegment>
</Accounting>
<Charge>
<Money currency="USD"/>
</Charge>
</Distribution>
<Distribution>
<Accounting name="DistributionCharge">
<AccountingSegment id="">
<Name xml:lang="en-US"/>
<Description xml:lang="en-US"/>
</AccountingSegment>
<AccountingSegment id="">
<Name xml:lang="en-US"/>
<Description xml:lang="en-US"/>
</AccountingSegment>
</Accounting>
<Charge>
<Money currency="USD"/>
</Charge>
</Distribution>
<Comments xml:lang="en-US"/>
</ItemOut>
</OrderRequest>
</Request>
</cXML>
```

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the XSD part. When I load it into Eclipse' schema editor all lines with `<xs:attribute ref=xml:lang/>` are marked as having an error. It references an attribute that don't seem to exist elsewhere in the file.

Comment: Even if I remove xml:lang="en-US" from xml and generate XSD from it, it has 2nd problem which I mentioned above.

Comment: So you have generated XSD from XML? I usually do the reverse.

Comment: I think your main problem is the xsd generator you used. It doesn't seem to generate a 100% valid schema.

Comment: I rephrase my question. I am trying to bind CXML DTD using JAXB. None of the DTD are abe to bind.You can find dtd on http://xml.cxml.org/current/cXML_DTDs.zip.